# Access OpenVPN client via SSH tunnel?

Tags: openvpn, ssh-tunnel

I know this sound weird, but...

I have a chromebook that connects to my VPS via a SSH tunnel over port 8080(because it can't connect to openvpn). My raspberry pi is connection to the VPN on the same VPS with the internal ip of 10.10.0.2. How can I access it with my chromebook on the SSH tunnel? 10.10.0.1, which is my VPS's IP in the VPN network works, but 10.10.0.2 just doesn't load.

Comment: You have to ssh into the VPS and then ssh into the rpi. The VPS is the jump host in this case. SSH has an option for that. The manpage should give you the instructions on using the jump host feature

Comment: I can't ssh into the RPi from the VPS, only from other devices on the VPN